# Suppose $\exists a\in (G, \cdot), a\neq e$ with $G\setminus \{a\}\le G$. Prove that $(G,\cdot) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb Z,+)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Consider a group $(G,\cdot)$ with the property that $\exists a\in G, a\neq e$, such that $G\setminus \{a\}$ is a subgroup of $G$. Prove that $(G,\cdot) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb Z,+)$.

We know that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $\forall x \in H, y\in G\setminus H$ we have that $xy \in G \setminus H$.
In our case, $\forall x\neq a$, $xa \in G \setminus (G\setminus \{a\})=\{a\}$ and this implies that $\forall x\neq a$, $x=e$.
As a result, $G=\{e,a\}$ and it is well-known and easy to prove that any group of order $2$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb Z,+)$.

I would like to know if my proof is correct.

Comment: looks correct! If you want another proof, it follows immediately from Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: @Ferra Thank you ! However, it doesn't follow from Lagrange's theorem because $G$ is not finite.

Comment: Yes you're right. Then you can see it this way: $G$ can be written as a disjoint union of cosets, all of which are in bijection with $H$. Thus if $G\setminus \{a\}$ is a subgroup, then $\{a\}$ is a coset, thus all cosets contain exactly one element, and the claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

Let $|G|=m$. The order of $G-\{a\}$ is $m-1$. If this set is a subgroup, then by Lagrange's theorem, $m-1\vert m$. The only integer $m$ satisfying this condition is 2, so $|G|=2$.

The only group of order 2, up to isomorphism, is $\left(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},+\right)$, hence the result.

Comment: You are assuming that $G$ is finite (because of the hypothesis of Lagrange's Theorem), right?

Comment: Yes, since the condition that removing an element yields a subgroup does not make sense for infinite groups, as far as I know.

Comment: @bluestool why wouldn't it make sense for infinite groups?

Comment: Because removing 1 element from a group removes closure under products if the group is infinite

Comment: @bluestool Could you prove this? I don't see why this holds for any infinite group.

Comment: I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3459049) to get a rigorous argument as to why this is the case. I'm almost certain it should be true, and I can support it heuristically, but I cannot think of a rigorous argument to prove it.